# disable ssl for mysql client apps

Tags: mysql, ssl, lets-encrypt

I have set up SSL for mysql replication. The problem is, that it makes problems on the other local apps which use mysql.

Like postfix:

```
Jul 25 23:00:22 srv1 postfix/proxymap[3141]: warning: connect to mysql server 127.0.0.1: SSL connection error: unable to verify peer checksum
Jul 25 23:00:22 srv1 postfix/trivial-rewrite[3353]: warning: virtual_mailbox_domains: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf: table lookup problem
Jul 25 23:00:22 srv1 postfix/trivial-rewrite[3353]: warning: virtual_mailbox_domains lookup failure
```

or amavis:

```
Jul 25 23:08:12 srv1 amavis[5625]: (05625-01) (!)connect_to_sql: unable to connect to DSN 'DBI:mysql:database=dbispconfig;host=127.0.0.1;port=3306': SSL connection error: unable to verify peer checksum
```

and also pureftp

```
Jul 25 23:02:42 srv1 pure-ftpd: (?@2a02:810c:XXXXXXXX) [ERROR] The SQL server seems to be down [SSL connection error: unable to verify peer checksum]
```

Because I dont need local encryption, i want to disable it, but I dont know how.
I have only set a cnf entry for the clients with:

```
[client]
#ssl-ca=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/chain.pem
#ssl-mode=DISABLED
ssl=0
```

But without luck. For postfix I found in the [docs](http://www.postfix.org/MYSQL_README.html) this note:

> Postfix 3.1 and earlier don't read [client] option group settings
>   unless a non-empty option_file or option_group value are specified. To
>   enable this, specify, for example "option_group = client".

So I added to all /etc/postfix/mysql-*.cf files the option_group syntax. But after the restart it is the same problem..

When I disable ssl on the server, the problems are gone. But I want to have ssl for security of the replication.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I have this same problem, but with samhain. My client machine has mysql8 client but the server is mysql 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few ideas.

1. Use `postconf` to see if there are any mistypes or incompatibilities in configuration files of Postfix. This utility complains when there are unused parameters.
2. Do not enforce the use of SSL on a server side. Instead, configure replication client to refuse insecure connections.
3. Use the feature of MySQL server 5.7 that allow changing SSL/TLS requirements per user via `CREATE USER ... REQUIRE ...` and `ALTER USER ... REQUIRE ...` and remove mandatory SSL for local clients.
4. Since postfix uses libmysqlclient, it should be possible to override location where postfix looks for my.cnf and use `[mysql]` section instead. It should be feasible to do this via [MYSQL_HOME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/environment-variables.html) environmental variable, but I doubt it is a good idea even to try :)